# Why does "yield" work in a recursive function

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

When I try to implement a permutation function, I got this code from web.

```
def permutations(seq):    
    if len(seq) == 1:
        yield seq
    else:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            perms = permutations(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:])
            for p in perms:
                yield [seq[i], *p]
```

I tried to unserstand the code but I failed, because I can't understand how to use yield recursively. I know every time I do next(generator), It run the code in body and stop at a yield statement. But how can it reach base condition if I only do next once cause it's obvious I have to do recursion multiple times before I can reach base(len == 1).
Based on my understanding, the yield from the bottom line should be return.

Comment: What do you mean by that: _"if I only do next once"_? `for p in perms` calls `next` rather often on `perms`.

Comment: @Timus I mean call next on generator. If a = permutations([1,2,3]) and do next(a), this is "do next once", sorry for my poor writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this works is as follows: in the loops body of the recursive branch of the condition, first you perform:

```py
            perms = permutations(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:])
```

This create a local generator object within the current recursion step.

The next two lines:

```py
            for p in perms:
                yield [seq[i], *p]
```

iterate over all the values generated by that generator object, and yields permutation based on them.

The `yield` statement does not "penetrate" recursion, but your code collects the value yielded from a recursive call, and then yields results based on them.

There is in fact a lot of yielding going on here - proportional to the factorial of the length of `seq`, but that would be expected, based on the size of your output.